# Customize DB2 docker image

Tags: docker, db2

IBM provides a Docker image for DB2 which is available at https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2

As documented in Docker Hub, it is possible to configure the database by creating a derived Docker image with an additional script (added in  /var/custom) with all the necessary customizations (for instance creating a schema).

```
FROM ibmcom/db2

RUN mkdir /var/custom
COPY createschema.sh /var/custom
RUN chmod a+x /var/custom/createschema.sh
```

This script is executed when the container starts, after the Db2 setup has completed.

Is there a way to build a Docker image where the script is pre-executed ?

I would like the database to be configured in the image itself so that a new container spawn from the image does not have to perform the initialization step when starting.

The script cannot just be executed in the Dockerfile with the RUN command as the DB2 setup is only performed when the container starts. Is there a way to trigger this setup and then run the custom configuration script directly in the Dockerfile?

If I try to execute the setup script (which is the ENTRYPOINT in the official image and which I could alter to customize the image) :

```
FROM ibmcom/db2
ENV LICENSE=accept
RUN /var/db2_setup/lib/setup_db2_instance.sh
```

There is a failure when starting DB2 I don't know how to resolve :

```
Starting DB2...

02/28/2021 09:54:31     0   0   SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.
```

I could create an image from a running container (with `docker commit`), but I would like to keep the image build process automated by a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Generic steps for this case are:

1. Find the ENTRYPOINT of the image and analyze how the image is initialized after the creation
2. Prepare new dockerbuild file that will

   1. Invoke the ENTRYPOINT command to initialize the image with `RUN`
   2. Run your own scripts
   3. Shut down the processes that ware initialized to flush the buffers (this is important for database images)
   4. Create new ENTRYPOINT if required

What you are doing till now is the correct steps, but you need to make sure you will shut-down the database at the end of the image build to force the changes of the database to be written to files.
Also you need to analyze the impact of the initializing the database inside the container on the starting process of the new image (ex. using volume mounts).

SQL1042C is associated with file corruption, however you can find more details in the database logs and verify the exact problem.

Comment: I can't find the root cause of SQL1042C in the DB2 logs.
My assumption is that the issue comes from the way the base DB2 image is defined. It defines a /database VOLUME. To my understanding, it means a new unnamed volume will be created automatically for this mount point at container start. However, by running the ENTRYPOINT script in my Dockerfile, it already tries to write data on this path (on a volume that has been declared but is not yet created). I am not sure how this is handled by the docker build command and if it may be the cause of SQL1042C.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot "undefine" the volume in my Dockerfile and redirecting all data to another path than /database might mean having to rewrite a large set of scripts in the base image.

Comment: One approach is to move data files (/database) after initialization to another folder, than write new starting script where the script will check if the /database is empty (new container mounted empty database) and copy back the files from the temporary folder to the /database before starting the database daemon.